# Debug conio.h using gdb

Tags: c++, emacs, gdb, conio

I'm using Emacs and gdb to debug a c++ program that uses `conio`'s `getch`. Something like the following:

```
#include <conio.h>

int main(){
  int c = getch();
  cout << (char) c;
}
```

If I place a breakpoint in the first line of the `main`, `gdb` hangs and nothing happens. I don't think a input file (`run < input.txt`) would work.

How should I debug it?

Answer (score 0):

`set new-console on` will open a new terminal which you can type in and `getch` will work.

Other methods might work too, but I think that this one is fine.